# Google Big Query Timestamp Format

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I'm trying to convert timestamp field to human-readable format. However, format_timestamp function and format_date & format_time functions are both returning different dates. I wonder which one is the one that I should go with?

[image]

NOTE: timestamp area is INT and nullable

Comment: event_date and event_timestamp are two different columns and are not guaranteed to contain the same date

Comment: I guess event_timestamp field is a timestamp format of event_date field. don't you think?

Comment: But obviously, it is not because 1698186891681599 isTue Oct 24 2023 22:34:51 GMT+0000, see https://www.unixtimestamp.com. your event_date is Oct 16 2023

Comment: So you saying event_timestamp is completely different field than event_date field. Than I can not proceed the time from the event_timestamp field. I see your point

Answer (score 1):

The `event_timestamp` field and the `event_date` field appear to be related, but their exact relationship depends on the specific schema of your dataset.

From the query you provided, it seems that you are using `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP` to format the **event_timestamp** field, and you are also using `FORMAT_DATE` to format the **event_date** field. This suggests that event_timestamp might represent a full timestamp (including both date and time), while event_date represents only the date portion.

To confirm whether event_timestamp is a timestamp format of event_date, you would need to examine the dataset's schema and data. You should look at the data types, values, and sample records to determine the relationship between these fields.

If event_timestamp contains both date and time information and event_date is a date component extracted from it, you can verify this by checking if the date portion of the formatted event_timestamp matches the event_date value. If they match, it's likely that event_timestamp is a full timestamp, and event_date is derived from it.

Keep in mind that without the specific schema and data, it's challenging to provide a definitive answer, and you should consult your dataset documentation or data source to understand the meaning and relationship between these fields.